# Mobile CSS Polish/Touch-up Issue on Website

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a mobile version of the following site: http://provenioexclusive.com

The CSS works perfect on Desktop, laptop, and iPad devices. However, when the window size is adjusted for mobile devices, the width for the product listings are all messed up. pls help
I've set the following container, " ul.products " to a width of 100% and applied another 100% to ".card.card-product" but that didn't work.

The "cards" should be the same width, the same width that the guy with the black shirt is in.

Screenshot attached, many thanks.

[image]

Comment: I think you have to remove the floating of your boxes :)

Comment: remove the `width: 48%;` in your `.woocommerce[class*=columns-] ul.products li.product {...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `@media (max-width: 767px)` use the following:

```
.woocommerce[class*=columns-] ul.products li.product {
    width: 100vw;
    float: none;
    clear: both;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Result:

[image]